# Link an excel file to an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, sharepoint, iframe

Trying to load a link from SharePoint using iFrame, but I can't seem to load it there.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadIframe(url) {
    document.getElementByName('iframe').src=url;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var myList = $(".root.ms-core-listMenu-root.static");

var dealsoldcurrentmonth = '<li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="" id="dealsoldcurrentmonth"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Deals Sold - Current Month</span></span></a></li>'
;myList.prepend(dealsoldcurrentmonth);
$("#dealsoldcurrentmonth").onclick(function() {loadIframe('http://c1w00168.itcs.hp.com/worldwide/dealuniverseww/_layouts/15/xlviewer.aspx?id=/worldwide/dealuniverseww/Shared%20Documents/Deal%20Universe%20WW%20-%20Deals%20Sold%20(Current%20Month).xlsx')});
$("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: So what happens *instead* of it working?

Comment: Current data in frame doesn't change. Links for redirection doesn't work. @TimWilliams